# Tell Angular to render dynamically html added by jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular

i have the situation that i want to use a jquery library in my angular (4)
project. I can programatially add some html content to this library, pseudo code:

```
someJQueryLib.addContent("<some-html-code></some-html-code>")
```

Now i want to use angular components in this html string like

```
someJQueryLib.addContent("<some-angular-component></some-angular-component>")
```

But the jQuery library adds the content dynamically so angular does not pick it up.

Is there a way to tell Angular that it should render the dynamically added HTML?

In AngularJS 1 you could use the `$compile` service to accomplish this. Was not a very beautiful way, but it worked.

Comment: possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: You need to compile a component with that template content at runtime. Angular doesn't process HTML added to a component dynamically.

Comment: @mr.void no, no duplicate, i do not need a dynamic component

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer yes, i know, but how can i tell angular to process this html?

Comment: See above comments.